# Spring REST controller using content-type multipart/related

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I need to write Spring REST controller using content-type as `multipart/related`. I couldn't make it work. 
Following code works fine with content-type as `content-type multipart/form-data`.

```
//working code with content-type multipart/form-data//
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public FileMetadataResource post(
        @Validated({ Default.class, PostCheck.class }) @RequestPart("resource") FileMetadataResource resource,
        @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file) {
    return fileService.create(resource, file);
}
```

I did the little research and found following.

1) [HTTPServletRequest](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getParts--).getParts() works only with `multipart/form-data`
2) Since Spring depends on underlying Servlet api, I couldn't find any way to get the `Parts` POSTed with content-type as `multipart/related`.

Not sure I am missing something. Please help me how to implement POST method for content-type as `multipart/related`.

Thanks,
Raj

Comment: You might be stuck just using the input stream and parsing yourself, don't see support for `multipart/related` in the servlet spec.

Comment: I am trying, but inputStream is already read by spring framework and it is closed. here is the error.
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: getInputStream() has already been called for this request
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getReader(Request.java:1189)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getReader(RequestFacade.java:503)`

Comment: can you post the code in the create method?